# Error :- the cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following query:

```
int? Giver = Convert.ToInt32(db.vwAssignments.Sum(a => a.Amount));
```

but if there is no records that matches the search criteria then the following error will be raised

> The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

pls help

Comment: Are you trying to sum a value of null?

Comment: When records are there working fine but if there is no record then raised errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basics of defensive programming:

- first assign the result of your `Sum()` operation to a nullable variable

  ```
  object resultOfSum = db.vwAssignments.Sum(a => a.Amount);
  ```
- **check for NULL!** and only if it's not null, **then** convert it to an `INT`

  ```
  if(resultOfSum != null)
  {
     int Giver = Convert.ToInt32(resultOfSum);   
  }
  ```

Also: if your `Amount` field is a `Int` to start with, most likely this will **already** give you NULL or a valid `Int` - I think that call to `Convert.ToInt32()` is not necessary:

```
int? Giver = db.vwAssignments.Sum(a => a.Amount);

if(Giver.HasValue)
{
   ......
}
```